# animation with matplotlib 'format "rgba" is not supported'

Tags: python, macos, animation, matplotlib, macports

I'm trying to make an animation with matplotlib, using the examples [from here](http://jakevdp.github.com/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/).  At first the problem was ffmpeg wasn't installed, so I installed that from macports - but not it's saying that 'rgba' is not supported.  The error message:

```
File "Plot_shocktube1D.py", line 85, in <module>
    animDensity.save(densityAnimationName, extra_args=['-vcodec', 'libx264']) #, writer=movWriter)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 615, in save
    writer.grab_frame()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 199, in grab_frame
    dpi=self.dpi)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1363, in savefig
    self.canvas.print_figure(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 2012, in print_figure
    print_method = self._get_print_method(format)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 1953, in _get_print_method
    '%s.' % (format, ', '.join(formats)))
ValueError: Format "rgba" is not supported.
Supported formats: bmp, emf, eps, gif, jpeg, jpg, pdf, pgf, png, ps, raw, rgba, svg, svgz, tif, tiff.
```

Now, after some struggling I setup a `FFMpegWriter` using `png` instead of `rgba`, but now I'm getting new errors...

```
movWriter = anim.FFMpegWriter(fps=5, codec=None, bitrate=None, extra_args=None, metadata=None)
movWriter.frame_format = 'jpg'
animDensity = anim.FuncAnimation(fig, animateDensity, frames=10, interval=100, blit=True)
animDensity.save(densityAnimationName, extra_args=['-vcodec', 'libx264'], writer=movWriter)
```

with errors:

```
File "Plot_shocktube1D.py", line 85, in <module>
    animDensity.save(densityAnimationName, extra_args=['-vcodec', 'libx264'], writer=movWriter)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 615, in save
    writer.grab_frame()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 199, in grab_frame
    dpi=self.dpi)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1363, in savefig
    self.canvas.print_figure(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 2093, in print_figure
    **kwargs)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_macosx.py", line 326, in print_jpg
    self._print_bitmap(filename, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_macosx.py", line 319, in _print_bitmap
    self.write_bitmap(filename, width, height, dpi)
ValueError: Unknown file type
```

I'm getting the impression I just don't have something installed that I need to...  generally macports sets me up with everything, and I'm not really sure where to look.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That use() statement didn't help me, but I ran into the same errors as you trying to get the second part of the [basic matplotlib animation example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/basic_example.html) working in IPython.  I used macports to install ffmpeg, and then was getting that same rgba not supported warning (despite rgba appearing in the list of supported formats!).

Anyway, I found that if I used an explict FFMpegFileWriter (not just FFMpegWriter), everything was OK, and the rgba issue went away and I got a usable m4v file:

```
import matplotlib.animation as animation
fig2 = plt.figure()

x = np.arange(-9, 10)
y = np.arange(-9, 10).reshape(-1, 1)
base = np.hypot(x, y)
ims = []
for add in np.arange(15):
    ims.append((plt.pcolor(x, y, base + add, norm=plt.Normalize(0, 30)),))

im_ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig2, ims, interval=50, repeat_delay=3000, blit=True)
im_ani.save('im.m4v', writer=animation.FFMpegFileWriter(), metadata={'artist':'Guido'})
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution, I have no idea why, is make matplotlib use something called "Agg":

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Agg")
```

Comment: I didn't know why either, but this explains: http://matplotlib.org/faq/howto_faq.html#matplotlib-in-a-web-application-server